# How to set DIV width/height with Javascript in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, firefox

The following works in IE, but not Firefox:

```
var el = $get('divToMask');
var box = Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(el);

var maskEl = $get('maskDiv');

// Only seems to work in IE
maskEl.style.width = box.width;
maskEl.style.height = box.height;

Sys.UI.DomElement.setLocation(maskEl, box.x, box.y);
```

box.width and box.height contain the correct values, but Firefox ignores the maskEl.style .width/.height methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note: I'm not familiar with the Javascript helper library you are using.

I'd guess that you need to change the two lines after your comment to the following:

```
maskEl.style.width = box.width + "px";
maskEl.style.height = box.height + "px";
```

Comment: It's the ASP.NET AJAX library. That did the trick... simple when you know how ;-)

Comment: it is not working in my case using firefox 10.0.2 writing this
var divPatient = $("#divPatient");
divPatient.style.height = "20px";
It says divPatient.style is undefined